# How to not get this warning? DB2 Warning SQLSTATE=02000 No row was found for FETCH, UPDATE, or DELETE; or the result of a query is an empty table

Tags: sql, db2, warnings

The way we have our error handling setup this warning will shoot an email out to everyone when it occurs (I can't change this). I really don't care that no rows were found for this job.

How do I either

A) Check if a row is present before tying to delete it or

B) Circumvent/ignore this warning somehow?

Example of the delete:

```
 delete from schema.table 
   where key is null;
```

`SQLSTATE=02000 No row` error was displayed for FETCH, UPDATE, or DELETE; or the result of a query is an empty table.

I cannot insert a dummy record to delete either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this will do

```
with delete_rows as (
  select * from old table (delete from schema.table where key is null)
)
select count(*) from delete_rows
```

Comment: This is what ended up working for me... probably wont work for everyone since our system is a little funky but it's close to your answer.

delete from schema.table where exists(select 1 from schema.table where key is null)

Comment: @AdamTheD Sure ?, `delete from schema.table where exists(select 1 from schema.table where key is null)` deletes every row in the table if one exists where key is null

Comment: The actual solution was to ignore the return code, I'll use 0 since idr the actual code, if[[$rtn_cd -ne 0]]; then echo "delete failed" exit $rtn_cd fi

Answer (score 0):

You may try [Compound SQL (compiled) statement](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/db2/11.5?topic=statements-compound-sql-compiled) "eating" this warning.

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND
  BEGIN END;
  DELETE ...;
END
```